# pythonic way to find first index that does not match in 2 strings

Tags: python

I want to know at which index do two strings stop matching.

For example:

```
a = "happy birthday"
b = "happybirthday"
```

Strings `a` and `b` stop matching on index 5 (0 based).

I know I can write my method like so:

```
  def compare_2_string(a, b):
    for x in xrange(len(a)):
      if a[x] != b[x]:
        return x
```

but is there a shorter, concise or pythonic way of doing the same logic?

Answer (score 4):

Use [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html):

```
>>> s1 = "happy birthday"
>>> s2 = "happybirthday"
>>> s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, s1, s2)
>>> m = s.get_matching_blocks()
>>> print m[0][2]
5
```

(`m` is a list of tuples, and the 3rd element of each tuple is the size of the block that matched. In real code you'd want to make sure that there actually was a match at all, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> next(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x[1][0] == x[1][1], enumerate(itertools.izip_longest(a, b))))[0]
5
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `next` with a generator expression. This will also work for strings of different lengths:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> next((i for i, (x, y) in enumerate(izip_longest(a, b)) if x != y), None)
5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
(i for (i, (e1, e2)) in enumerate(zip(a, b)) if e1 != e2).next()
=> 5
```

Answer (score 1):

I went for the zip/enumerate answer as well; my feeling is that the 'most Pythonic' shape is a classic function rather than wrapping next() around itertools or a generator expression, but YMMV. Mine is:

```
def compare_2_strings(s1, s2):
    for charPos, (s1Char, s2Char) in enumerate(zip(s1, s2)):
        if not s1Char == s2Char:
            return charPos
```

If the strings are the same, it will return None ("absence of a character position where they differ").

Chasing alternative shapes, I have:

```
def compare_2_strings(a, b):
    import itertools
    return len(list((itertools.takewhile(lambda s: operator.eq(*s), zip(a, b)))))
```

If they are identical strings, it will return their length.

It's uglier, longer code, less Pythonic, *and* does more work. What more could you want?